# Python 3.7+: Wait until result is produced - api/task system

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In the following code, an API gives a task to a task broker, who puts it in a queue, where it is picked up by a worker. The worker will then execute the task and notify the task broker (using a redis message channel) that he is done, after which the task broker will remove it from its queue. This works.
What I'd like is that the task broker is then able to return the result of the task to the API. But I'm unsure on how to do so since it is asynchronous code and I'm having difficulty figuring it out. Can you help?

Simplified the code is roughly as follows, but incomplete.

The API code:

```
@router.post('', response_model=BaseDocument)
async def post_document(document: BaseDocument):
    """Create the document with a specific type and an optional name given in the payload"""
    task = DocumentTask({ <SNIP>
    })

    task_broker.give_task(task)
    result = await task_broker.get_task_result(task)
    return result
```

The task broker code, first part is giving the task, the second part is removing the task and the final part is what I assume should be a blocking call on the status of the removed task

```
    def give_task(self, task_obj):
        self.add_task_to_queue(task_obj)
        <SNIP>
        self.message_channel.publish(task_obj)

    # ...
    def remove_task_from_queue(self, task):
        id_task_to_remove = task.id
        for i in range(len(task_queue)):
            if task_queue[i]["id"] == id_task_to_remove:
                removed_task = task_queue.pop(i)
                logger.debug(
                    f"[TaskBroker] Task with id '{id_task_to_remove}' succesfully removed !"
                )
                removed_task["status"] = "DONE"
                return
     # ...

       async def get_task_result(self, task):
            return task.result
```

My intuition would like to implement a way in get_task_result that blocks on task.result until it is modified, where I would modify it in remove_task_from_queue when it is removed from the queue (and thus done).

Any idea in how to do this, asynchronously?

Comment: If everything runs in the same process, you could have an `asyncio.Event` for each task that your `post_document` can await on (and the completion handler would set). If things are not in the same process, you need an external signaling system (e.g. Redis is easy enough) or you'll have to poll for the task status.

Comment: If you are able to know if the task was done, why don't you send the result in that message? Or at least a pointer to its location.